# How to show button on specific name in angular table

Tags: angular, button

**I only need to show Cancel button when status is Initiated but when is Changed it should be disabled or gone completely.**

`
    
    
      {{ 'Recipient' | translate }}
       {{row.recipient.name}}

```
<!-- status.name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="status.name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Status' | translate }}</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" aria-label="status" data-label="status.name">
    {{row.status.name}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>....


<!-- cancle Transaction Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="cancel" >
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngClass]="'widthCancel'">{{ 'Cancel Transaction' | translate }}</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" aria-label="cancel" data-label="transaction" [ngClass]="'widthCancel'">
      <button mat-button color="warn" class="cancel-transaction" matTooltip="Cancel initiated transaction"  (click)="onCancelTransaction()">{{ 'Cancel' | translate }}</button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
</mat-row>
```

`

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) on the container that checks the value of status.

eg:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="status ==== 'Initiated'" matColumnDef="cancel" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is through *ngIf directive:

```
<button mat-button *ngIf="status === 'Initiated'" color="warn" class="cancel-transaction" matTooltip="Cancel initiated transaction"  (click)="onCancelTransaction()">{{ 'Cancel' | translate }}</button>
```

In this case button will appear only when variable status will have string value 'Initiated'

Comment: I try it but everything is gone now all cancel buttons, but Thank you very much

Comment: You must edit condition according to your needs. I don't know if Initiated is string or some enum or what.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<button mat-button  [disabled]="status != 'Initiated'" color="warn" class="cancel-transaction" matTooltip="Cancel initiated transaction"  (click)="onCancelTransaction()">
  {{ 'Cancel' | translate }}
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you I solved it i only add row and name   [disabled]="row.status.name !== 'Initiated'"

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer that helped